# How to add total and percentage column for splunk timechart command

Tags: charts, splunk, stat, splunk-query

Using a simple example:  count the number of events for each host name

... | timechart count BY host

```
> ... | timechart count BY host
> 
> This search produces this results table:
> 
> _time         host1   host2   host3   
> 
> 2018-07-05    1038    27      7      
> 2018-07-06    4981    111     35      
> 2018-07-07    5123    99      45       
> 2018-07-08    5016    112     22
```

What I want is to add a column to show the total events for that day and the percentage of each http status code.

I tried

```
 ... | timechart count BY host
| eval total= host1 + host2 + host3
| eval host1_percent = host1 / total
| eval host2_percent = host2 / total
| eval host3_percent = host3 / total
| table _time, host1_percent, host2_percent, host3_percent
```

This works most of the time, but I found out if for certain day, a host was offline (no record for a particular host), then the search doesn't work (return blank results), I have to remove that particular host from the "total = host1 + host2 + host3" to get it to work.

So my question is: is there a way to get the total number of record for for every day (row) without having to add them together, e.g. replace the "total = host1 + host2 + host3" with a count or sum, I tried couple of thing, none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know what you've tried so far so we don't suggest the same things.

Have you tried `addtotals`?

```
| timechart count by host
| addtotals row=true fieldname=total host*
```